# Create matrix from matrix of indices in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix in the format

```
A 2 x
A 3 y
A 4 z
B 1 a
B 12 b
```

I want to reshape it assuming that the second column is an index from 1-12

```
A 0 x y z 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
B a 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 b
```

Comment: Please use proper MATLAB syntax for your "matrix" such that it can be copied and pasted directly into MATLAB. At the moment, we don't know if it's supposed to be a cell array of strings or if your letters are supposed to just be illustrative place holders for numbers etc

Comment: Also, please try this yourself first using the `sub2ind` function. You might find the 3rd output from `unique` useful as well

Comment: Sorry asking this query over my phone so typing the bare minimum. Everything in cell array is fine.

Comment: "Everything in cell array is fine" - what does that mean???

Comment: You can assume cell array instead of double. That's what I suppose you asked. Thanks for sub2ind function. I am new to Matlab and didn't know of the function.

Comment: You show no regard for others time and effort by saying, "I'm on my phone and can't be bothered to write an intelligent and thoughtful question."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is:

- get the number of uniques in first column and the max value in the second, to know how large the result is;
- allocate memory for the result;
- populate the first column with the uniques;
- populate the rows with the indexed values.

Which is:

```
    %'Some matrix (that the OP should have provided...)'
    M0 = [
       1 2 4;
       1 3 6;
       3 4 2;
       2 1 1;
       2 12 10
    ];

    %'Allocate space for result'
    U  = unique(M0(:,1));
    L  = max(M0(:,2));
    M1 = zeros(numel(U), L+1); 

    %'Populate result'
    M1(:,1) = U(:);
    for k = 1:numel(U)
            IX = (M0(:,1)==U(k));
            M1(k,M0(IX,2)+1) = M0(IX,3);
    end;
```

This should work for arbitrary large `M0` and arbitrary number of uniques in its first column.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple and dirty solution.

```
M = {'A', '2', 'x'; 'A', '3', 'y'; 'A', '4', 'z'; 'B', '1', 'a'; 'B', '12', 'b'};

for l = 1:length(M)
    n = 1 + double(M{l, 1}) - double('A');
    m = str2double(M{l, 2});

    R{n, m} = M{l, 3};
end

[R{cellfun(@(x) isempty(x), R)}] = deal('0');
```

Result:

```
>> R = 
'0'    'x'    'y'    'z'    '0'    '0'    '0'    '0'    '0'    '0'    '0'    '0'
'a'    '0'    '0'    '0'    '0'    '0'    '0'    '0'    '0'    '0'    '0'    'b'
```